# Any example of condition number of matrix less than 1?

Tags: matrices, condition-number

Any example of the condition number of matrix less than 1? In our lectures, my professor defined the condition number under the matrix norms. i.e. $$K(A) = ||A^{-1}||_M||A||_M$$

Comment: Isn't the condition number defined as $\sigma_{\max}/\sigma_{\min}$, where $\sigma_{\max}$ is the largest singular value and $\sigma_{\min}$ is the smallest? This ratio can't be less than $1$, by definition. Are you using some other definition?

Comment: @Bungo So if a matrix is not a square matrix does not affect the result?

Comment: @Justin What result?  If $A$ is not a square matrix, there is no such thing as $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition number $\kappa(A)$ of a complex square matrix $A$ is usually defined as $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ for some *induced* matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$. Since the matrix norm is induced from a vector norm, it is submultiplicative and $\|I\|=1$. It follows that $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|\ge\|AA^{-1}\|=\|I\|=1$, i.e. the condition number is always $\ge1$.

Comment: What if the condition "complex square matrix" is replaced by any matrix?

Comment: @Justin What any matrix?

Comment: For any matrix A, we have $$K(A)>=1$$, is this correct?

Comment: @Justin I ain't sure how to define the condition number for "any" matrix. If it is a complex rectangular matrix $A$ of full column rank, you can define its condition number as $\|A^+\|_2\|A\|_2=\frac{\sigma_\max(A)}{\sigma_\min(A)}$, the ratio of the largest singular value of $A$ to the smallest one. The choices of matrix norms are essential here: we specifically use the induced $2$-norms $\|\cdot\|_2$. It may not make sense to use other norms in this case, because there may not exist a left inverse $A^+$ of $A$ such that $\|Ax-b\|$ is always minimised by $x=A^+b$, regardless of $x$ and $b$...

Comment: ...If $\kappa(A)$ is defined as $\frac{\sigma_\max(A)}{\sigma_\min(A)}$, then of course it is bounded below by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

For non-square complex matrices, the easier way is to define the condition number as the ratio between the largest and smallest singular values. From this definition it is clear that $\kappa$ is always greater than or equal to 1.